# Converting one column spark dataframe into Single String delimited by pipline character in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark data frame, which contains one column of information.  It looks like:

```
Name
----------
Bob


----------
Dan
```

I want to convert this into a single string, delimited by pipeline characters.

```
"Bob|Dan"
```

How would I go about doing so in Python (pyspark)? Currently, I'm creating the dataframe via

```
df = sqlContext.sql("Select name from db")
```

If you could help lead me in a certain direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([{'name':'Bob'},{'name':'Dan'}])

'|'.join([str(x.asDict().values()[0])  for x in df.collect()])
```

Comment: This function did the job.  I'm going to try to breakdown this function by looking through documentation, but if I have trouble, is it okay if I ask you for help understanding it?

Comment: just for refrence, asDict and collect are spark related, everything else is regular python

Answer (score 2):

You can use collect_list and concat from functions module,

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df.select(F.concat_ws('|',F.collect_list(df.name)).alias('name')).show()
+-------+
|   name|
+-------+
|Bob|Dan|
+-------+
```